# Java - How to call a function in sync and parallel that returns a string?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, future, executorservice

I need to call a function that returns a string. The UI provides a list of IDs for which I would need to call a function which creates a file and returns the filename. Currently, I'm calling the function in an iterative fashion. Upon completing each iteration, I'm putting the filename into an ArrayList which I will be using it later.

How can I call the function in parallel, and then add each of the result into an array list, and wait for all threads to complete, before doing the other piece of code?

Here's the sample piece of code I have.

```
List<String> fileNames=new ArrayList<>();

for (Object ob : objectList){
    String filename = createFilename(ob);
    fileNames.add(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Java 8+, this is a perfect use case for streams:

```
List<String> fileNames = objectList.parallelStream()
        .map(ob -> createFilename(ob))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```